# Api google maps não funciona com IP externo

Tags: google, maps

Tenho um servidor Debian linux onde eu desenvolvo meus sites. Tenho liberado um ip para que meus clientes possam ver os sites. Na parte onde fica o mapa de localização não aparece o mapa apenas se eu acesso localmente.

Para conseguir o api key para aceesar os mapas localmente coloquei la no google o Ip 192.168.10.2 que seria o IP interno da minha rede.

Quando colocco o IP externo o google nao aceita.

Minha pergunta é como eu posso fazer com que funcione pelo IP externo os maps do goole?